# Specifying "const" when overloading operators in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading, constants

Code:

```
4: typedef unsigned short  USHORT;
5: #include <iostream.h>
6:
7:     class Counter
8:     {
9:        public:
10:          Counter();
11:          ~Counter(){}
12:          USHORT GetItsVal()const { return itsVal; }
13:          void SetItsVal(USHORT x) {itsVal = x; }
14:          void Increment() { ++itsVal; }
15:          const Counter& operator++ ();
16:
17:       private:
18:          USHORT itsVal;
19:
20:    };
21:
22:    Counter::Counter():
23:    itsVal(0)
24:    {};
25:
26:    const Counter& Counter::operator++()
27:    {
28:       ++itsVal;
29:       return *this;
30:    }
31:
32:    int main()
33:    {
34:       Counter i;
35:       cout << "The value of i is " << i.GetItsVal() << endl;
36:       i.Increment();
37:       cout << "The value of i is " << i.GetItsVal() << endl;
38:       ++i;
39:       cout << "The value of i is " << i.GetItsVal() << endl;
40:       Counter a = ++i;
41:       cout << "The value of a: " << a.GetItsVal();
42:       cout << " and i: " << i.GetItsVal() << endl;
48:     return 0;
49: }
```

I'm studying overloading operators in C++ and can't wrap my head around the "const" specifier in line 26. The way I understood constant reference is that we are not allowed to change the value that is stored in the reference. But inside the operator++ function (lines 26-30), the member variable "itsVal" is incremented. Doesn't this violate the "const" requirement in the function's definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator is returning a reference to an internal parameter as a const reference, which means that client code can not modify the reference they receive from the operator.

If, on the other hand the member function itself was const:

```
const Counter& Counter::operator++() const
```

then the function would not be allowed to modify any of its members. As it stands it can do any modification it wants before returning the reference.

Comment: Oh I see. So `Counter& Counter::operator++() const` means the function can not change the member variables, and `const  Counter& Counter::operator++()` means the return object is a constant reference, correct? Then is the point of the "const" in my code to prevent the user from assigning a different value to i++ (for example `i++ = 500`)?

Comment: @user207886 Yes, it allows you to return a reference to the data (for performance reasons) without allowing clients the ability to modify the contents of your object; which they would be able to do if you returned a non-const reference.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the meaning of "const"!